# Using PHP to extract the core rules in IPTables output

Tags: php

Im trying to do the following;

I want the rules in the IPTables output extracted to a separate file. (just a text file in Debian). This has to be done through a PHP CLI script that runs on the Debian server.

However, I have no idea on how to do this efficiently, mostly because the output has clutter too. (First few lines declaring INPUT, OUTPUT, etc).

I've tried messing around with the head and tail commands in Debian but I did not succeed yet.

How can I do this the proper way?

An example;

results.txt

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s "$BLOCK_THIS_IP" -j DROP
```

An enter

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s "$BLOCK_THIS_IP" -j DROP
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the text file? Also, what means "I want to very rules"? What exactly do you want to do with the file?

Comment: Hi cen, Textfile is empty. I just want to extract the very core rules, as in for example, iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s "$BLOCK_THIS_IP" -j DROP in the text file. An enter should separate all entries.

Comment: So you want to execute a system command, store the result in a text file and then read that file with php? Something like: exec('iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s "$BLOCK_THIS_IP" -j DROP > results.txt');

Sorry if I am still missing your point.

Comment: No worries ken appreciate your help. What I want to have is a result.txt that stores the rules of IPtables, neatly sorted. I have to do this with a PHP CLI application. So, phpCLI-->get IPTables rules --> grab those rules, sort them on a .txt (separate file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research: https://wiki.debian.org/iptables

Example of iptables-save binary:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 224 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  162 26863 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 185 packets, 31967 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
$ sudo /sbin/iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Nov 18 11:43:19 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [8:432]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [699:111055]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 18 11:43:19 2013
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
// get content from command called
$processHandle = popen('/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables-save 2>&1', 'r');
$content = '';
while (!feof($processHandle)) {
    $content .= fread($processHandle, 4096);
}
pclose($processHandle);

// break out all new lines into an array
$lines = explode("\n", $content);

// parse through each line
$commands = '';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (empty($line)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^#/', $line) === 1) {
        continue;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^\*/', $line) === 1) {
        continue;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^COMMIT/', $line) === 1) {
        continue;
    }
    $match = array();
    if (preg_match('/^:([A-Z ]*).*/', $line, $match) === 1) {
        //echo "iptables -P {$match[1]}\n";
        continue;
    }
    $commands .= "iptables {$line}\n";
}

// write to a results file
$fileHandle = fopen("results", "w");
fwrite($fileHandle, $commands);
fclose($fileHandle);
?>
```

Runtime output:

```
$ php test3.php
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Great stuff! Trying to put the last echo in a file, however
 echo "iptables {$line}\n" > result; will not work, any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelP You can comment out this line `// echo "iptables -P {$match[1]}\n";` and then run `$ php test3.php > result`. Would that work or do you specifically need the php code to write it to a file?

Comment: @MichaelP Updated code to write all the iptables commands to a result file except for the default chains.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks again. Your updated code does exactly what I want and your clear style of coding made me understand the very core of it.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with:

```
$output = shell_exec('iptables -L');

$lines = explode("\n", $output);
$saveLines = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if (stripos($line, 'iptables') === 0) {
        $saveLines[] = $line;
    }
}

file_put_contents('path/to/the/file/that/will/contain/the/rules', implode("\n", $saveLines));
```

Having in mind that you can access `shell_exec` and the user that runs php has access to the iptables command.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't grab the concept of shell_exec so I didn't know it could be done this easily!